# How to create a Kubernetes cluster from within GitLab CI for e2e testing?

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, gcloud, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

I want to create a Google Cloud Kubernetes cluster programmatically in a GitLab CI script `.gitlab-ci.yml` in order to do e2e testing against it. Therefore I

- created a separate project `project-e2e` (in order to separate the billing)
- enabled Kubernetes Engine API
- created a service account `gitlab-ci@project-e2e.iam.gserviceaccount.com` with a key in JSON format which I'm providing through CI variables and using as shown below
- made the service account `App Engine Admin`, `Compute Admin`, `Kubernetes Engine Admin`, `Kubernetes Engine Cluster Admin`, `Editor`, `Service Account User` and `Owner` following permission-role mappings described at https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/api-permissions and https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam

The script however fails due to missing permissions of the created service account which should be covered by the assigned roles by as far as I understand (the output contains the commands the stage in the CI script consists of):

```
$ echo "$GOOGLE_KEY" > key.json
$ gcloud config set project project-e2e
Updated property [core/project].
$ gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file key.json --project project-e2e
Activated service account credentials for: [gitlab-ci@project-e2e.iam.gserviceaccount.com]
$ gcloud config set compute/zone us-central1-a
Updated property [compute/zone].
$ kubectl config get-contexts
CURRENT   NAME   CLUSTER   AUTHINFO   NAMESPACE
$ gcloud container clusters create project-e2e-$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA --project project-e2e --service-account=gitlab-ci@project-e2e.iam.gserviceaccount.com
WARNING: In June 2019, node auto-upgrade will be enabled by default for newly created clusters and node pools. To disable it, use the `--no-enable-autoupgrade` flag.
WARNING: Starting in 1.12, new clusters will have basic authentication disabled by default. Basic authentication can be enabled (or disabled) manually using the `--[no-]enable-basic-auth` flag.
WARNING: Starting in 1.12, new clusters will not have a client certificate issued. You can manually enable (or disable) the issuance of the client certificate using the `--[no-]issue-client-certificate` flag.
WARNING: Currently VPC-native is not the default mode during cluster creation. In the future, this will become the default mode and can be disabled using `--no-enable-ip-alias` flag. Use `--[no-]enable-ip-alias` flag to suppress this warning.
WARNING: Starting in 1.12, default node pools in new clusters will have their legacy Compute Engine instance metadata endpoints disabled by default. To create a cluster with legacy instance metadata endpoints disabled in the default node pool, run `clusters create` with the flag `--metadata disable-legacy-endpoints=true`.
WARNING: Your Pod address range (`--cluster-ipv4-cidr`) can accommodate at most 1008 node(s). 
This will enable the autorepair feature for nodes. Please see https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/node-auto-repair for more information on node autorepairs.
ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.create) ResponseError: code=403, message=Required "container.clusters.create" permission(s) for "projects/project-e2e". See https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting#gke_service_account_deleted for more info.
```

I tried

- omitting `--service-account=gitlab-ci@project-e2e.iam.gserviceaccount.com` which has no effect
- finding answers in https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting#gke_service_account_deleted which seems unrelated
- adding and omitting `--no-enable-legacy-authorization` which has no effect

[image]

Comment: In the doc you refer [here][1] says: 
>When you enable the Compute Engine or Kubernetes Engine API, a service account is created and given edit permissions on your project.
As I can see your service account is: gitlab-ci@project-e2e.iam.gserviceaccount.com which should have the permissions required, the same permissions as the one is created when Kubernetes is enabled. Have you double-checked that?
[1]:https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting#gke_service_account_deleted

Comment: Your service account should be "Kubernetes Engine Service Agent" role.

Comment: I tried your steps (by the way, great question, thanks for laying out your steps so clearly), and was able to create a cluster successfully. To ensure this wasn't a false positive, I revoked the permissions from the SA and tried to create another cluster, and got a 403 error. Are you completely sure you've associated those permissions to that particular SA in that particular project?

Comment: Couple other miscellaneous things: 1) I'm sure the permissions you're giving that SA are overkill, it does not need full project `Owner` permissions to create a GKE cluster. 2) Just so you're aware, the `--service-account` flag is specific to `gcloud container clusters` commands and determines what service account gets associated to cluster nodes, it is not the SA that is used to issue the GCloud API requests to create the cluster. Not sure if you were aware of that, but I'd recommend having a separate SA used in `gcloud auth activate-service-account` to create the cluster...

Comment: ... with just enough permissions to create clusters, and a separate SA (if any) that gets associated to nodes which is passed via the `--service-account` flag, if you need to allow nodes to do special cloud things like mount PDs. But most features should work by default without provisioning a special SA for this. Also, there's a separate `gcloud` command (that works for any command) called `--impersonate-service-account` which could be used to ensure GCloud API calls are being made by a particular SA, but that's unnecessary since you're already running `gcloud auth activate-service-account`.

Comment: @brauliobaron Thanks for you input. I realized that I have the same issue with the created service account (`service-337671704100@container-engine-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com` in this example). I added a screenshot of the IAM role mapping to the question. I added "Kubernetes Engine Service Agent" to both the automatically and manually created service accounts and tried both without success.

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta Thanks for the hint, I'm aware of the overkill roles. I was heading to assigning all possible roles in order to see whether anything works at all, but then I decided I want to understand the issue :). Do you have any more ideas for debugging?

Comment: I would suggest, until you have it working, keep the `Owner` permission. When you run these command locally, does it work?

Comment: The issue is still `ResponseError: code=403, message=Required "container.clusters.create" permission(s) for "projects/project-e2e"` ?

Comment: I'm suspicious that either the permissions of the roles or the assignment of the roles is extremely delayed in the background or that some `gcloud` command take the project name and some the project id and some both as argument for `--project`. This leads to situations where a precondition like authentification has suceeded, but then isn't recognized in the following steps. I'll investigate further and try to create a reproducer after you input, thanks.